# Limiting db table entries in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I have APIs exposed for a user to create different items which correspond to rows in different tables and I want to place a cap on how many can be created. Just wanted to know what the best practice is. I'm thinking that if a cap can be defined in the table (couldn't see anything in the 'create table' documentation), that should be clean, but I'm open to other ideas. I'm also using Yii so if there's anything in ActiveRecord, that would be cool too. I just want to avoid putting a count on the before save if possible.